# Specify lower Jackson version in Spring 3.1.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

This is the opposite of what most Spring users are clamoring to do, but I was wondering if its possible to specify that Jackson 1.9.7 be used by Spring (3.1.2) and NOT Jackson 2+.

The project I'm working on relies on other projects that use Jackson 2, so it get pulls in as a transitive dependency.  From there Spring picks it up to handle JSON serialization.  This in turn borks my application because of custom annotations I've created that require the Jackson version be 1.9.7.

Comment: And if you pull in jackson1 wouldn't the other project break? You shouldn't mix different versions of frameworks, it generally gives more trouble then the problem you initially want to solve.

Comment: @M.Deinum -- Jackson 1 and 2 actually are in different packages so this in and of itself is not an issue.  I generally agree that mixing different versions of the same library is less than optimal and I intend to rev our codebase to Jackson 2, but in the mean time I'm attempting to find a way for the two to play nice.

Comment: That is true, but Spring does some detection on which jackson version is available and depending on that does some automatic setup. But if you simply include jackson1 in your project that should be available (you might need to explicitly configure the `HttpMessageConverter` that is going to be used.

Comment: @M.Deinum -- I generally understand what's going on behind the scenes.  Though I don't fully understand the algorithm Spring uses to select 1.9.7 versus 2.x.  It seems to be deterministic based on static code, but if the dependency tree changes, it can swap the version it grabs.  Any insight into the selection process would be useful.  Basically this question boils down to: "Is there a simple way to configure Spring to use 1.9.7."  Do you have any example code of explicitly configuring a {{HttpMessageConverter}}?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but note that you can also add both Jackson 1 and Jackson 2 annotations in value classes. I have done this at work, to help transition from Jackson 1.9 to Jackson 2.x. And in fact different parts of code use different version: unit test helper methods were migrated first, and later on production code, section by section.

As with library version, use of two sets of annotations is not optimal, but doing so may help reduce risk of version upgrade.

Finally, it is also possible to use an `AnnotationIntrospector` that can use both sets of annotations (I don't have a link at hand, but I know a Jackson user published version he created); usually Jackson 2 `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` that also recognizes Jackson 1 annotations. This avoids duplication of annotations and makes it possible to upgrade code first, then convert annotations.